# Which L1K entrust certificates should be kept private?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, certificate

One of our client has made an update to his SSL certificate and he did send us a procedure to update the certificate on our side.  They also provided the L1Kchain.txt (that should be converted to a .cer) and a L1Kchainroot.txt.

First thing first: I'm not a system administrator; I'm a programmer and I never had to manage any SSL certificate.  I do understand the basics of the SSL protocol but I'm a bit concern because it's the first time of my life where I have to install a certificate manually on the client side.  I always thought that part would be done automatically once the server would update it's certificate.

I'm also concern about the certificates that was distributed... I always thought the only certificate that should be distributed publicly was the .crt files.  Ain't the L1Kchain.cer and the L1Kchainroot.txt suppose to be kept private (and let the SSL protocol update the public certificates on the clients)?

Answer (score 1):

Certificates are public. Private keys are private. The private key you generated before requesting the cert is what you need to be careful with.